# Laravel 5.7 - Multiple subdomains and databases in same project

Tags: php, database, laravel, subdomain

I am trying to develop an app in Laravel 5.7 that works with 4 subdomains and 2 databases in this way:

```
Route::domain('www.example.com.br', function($route) { 
    Route::get('/',  function() {
        #single route to the app welcome page
    })->name('welcome');
});

Route::domain('app.example.com.br', function($route) { 
    # connects with database "A"
    ...
    # app routes
    ...
});

Route::domain('dev.example.com.br', function($route) { 
    # connects with database "B"
    ...
    # app routes
    ...
});

Route::domain('sandbox.example.com.br', function($route) { 
    # connects with database "B"
    ...
    # app routes
    ...
});
```

The "app routes" are the same for the 3 enviroments (app, dev, sandbox).

If a user log in "app.example.com.br" and manually change for "dev.example.com.br", for example, the database changes and must lose the session.

And don't matter which enviroment(app, dev, or sandbox), all app routes must stay in this enviroment, in other words, the app cannot change the initial enviroment acessed by the user.

My problem is exactly this: I access "app.example.com.br" and do the login, the authentication works, but for same reason, I am redirected to "sandbox.example.com.br". I cannot stay in "app.example.com.br".

Comment: Welcome to SO, what is the question?

Comment: Thanks, I will edit my question.

Comment: With the code you posted is difficult to guess an answer. Please read carefully here on how to ask a question so you'll get a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have a look at the "multi tenancy" package for Laravel, this will allow you to use a single DB for authentication but run multiple databases for different "Tenants" it can be found here: https://laravel-tenancy.com/

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I think I found a solution: store the subdomain in session and test in a middleware if the subdomain is the same I stored. So if not, I break the session and redirect to the login page again.